# Add delimiter in txt file python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text, delimiter

I m trying to transfer data from a text file to csv.
My text file contains lots of rows delimited by /n.

```
a: data
b: data2
$e = data3
number
a: data4 and so on
```

I need a column for `a,b`, one for $ starting rows and a column for data after the `=` or `:` sign.

Can someone help me with a starting point?:)

Comment: Please tell final output you desire that make we can help you

Comment: a         b           Parameter                 Value                     Number --> the columns I need and for each column I need rows containing data, data2, data3, number.  @Lazyer

Comment: @Lazyer I know that I need to separate data to put it in table, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Which column should **$e = data3**, **number** enter?

Comment: @Lazyer Parameter equals e, so Parameter column means 'e' column, and Value comumn means 'data3'

Comment: And Number column should contain rows with number

Comment: Thank you:) I posted a more specific question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72643492/text-file-lines-to-csv-columns @Lazyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
txt = """a: data
b: data2
$e = data3
number
a: data4"""
txt_lines = txt.split("\n")
df_dict = dict()
for line in txt_lines:
    if ":" in line or "$" in line:
        # remove special character
        column = line.split()[0].replace("$", "").replace(":", "")
        # if column exists get row, if not, get empty list
        row = df_dict.get(column, list())
        # think as last word to data and update row
        row.append(line.split()[-1])
        # update dictionary
        df_dict.update({column: row})
    else:
        # if ":" or "$" not exists in text, then think as number
        column = 'number'
        # if column exists get row, if not, get empty list
        row = df_dict.get(column, list())
        # update row
        row.append(line)
        # update dictionary
        df_dict.update({column: row})
df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, pd.Series(v)) for k,v in df_dict.items()]))
```

df looks like it.

```
       a      b      e  number
0   data  data2  data3  number
1  data4    NaN    NaN     NaN
```

It'll be better people help you if you question after read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you:) I posted a more specific question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72643492/text-file-lines-to-csv-columns